# Java can't run cmd-command's properly

Tags: java, xslt, cmd, get, wmic

I am attempting to generate a list of all installed Programs on my Windows machine.

This is the command I am using:

```
WMIC /output:D:\miep product get name && type D:\miep > D:\miep_
```

You might have realized that I'm also trying to make a type-Command as I need the output in UTF-8.

I made a Whitelist for this with a simple loop where I will look later where in my file certain Names will appear and keep them while I remove everything else.

The command works in the command prompt, but when I try to do the same inside my Java Program it keeps telling me I've got an ***Invalid GET-Expression*** ...

Here is my function:

```
void createLists() throws IOException {
    //String cmd = "WMIC /output:D:\\miep.csv product get name /format:\"%WINDIR%\\System32\\wbem\\de-DE\\csv.xsl\"";
    String cmd = "WMIC /output:D:\\miep product get name && type D:\\miep > D:\\miep_";
    System.out.println(cmd);

    Process p;
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    p.getOutputStream().close();

    String line;
    BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    stdout.close();
    BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    while ((line = stderr.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    stderr.close();

    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

I also tried the converting stuff with the .csv files as you might have seen in the second line of my code and the same:
Works in CMD, but not in my Java-Program..!

Here it keeps telling me that it's an **Invalid XSL-Format**

Can someone help?

Comment: Instead of using `type` can you not just convert `D:\\miep` to utf8 in java?

Comment: how am I supposed to convert anything if I can't even create the file? Like I said before, the problem is that first off all I can't run the WMIC command...